# Update spesific element in behaviorsubject, or only subscribe once

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

Im having an `BehaviorSubject` that is getting continues updates every 5 secs from my other files.

But, somethimes i cant wait 5 sec for the new event to occur, so im looking for a way to update only one single element of the `Behaviorsubject`.

i have created the following to handle the single element:

```
 updateSingleTimer(timer,time,secs = false) {
    this.timers$.pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$)).subscribe((data:any) => {
      var newdata = data;
      newdata[timer] = time;
      this.updateTimers(newdata);
    });
  }
```

of course, this will create an infinity loop, cause timers is updated once `updateTimers` function is called.

So, i need to only get the timers data in `updateSingleTimer` function once, and not subscribe to it.

Q: How would i change the code above so it will only get result once from `this.timers$`?

*Q: also, is it possible to update one single element an easier way than what im doing currently?*

full code:

```
  _timers = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private timersChangeSet = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.timersChangeSet.subscribe(val => this._timers.next(val))
}

  timers$ = this._timers.asObservable();

updateTimers(object) {
    this.timersChangeSet.next(object);
  }


  updateSingleTimer(timer,time,secs = false) {

// the code will result in infinity loop, of course. but how would i only get the value once?
    this.timers$.pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$)).subscribe((data:any) => {
      var newdata = data;
      newdata[timer] = time;
      this.updateTimers(newdata);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take 1

```
this.timers$.pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
```